# testdriven.io: Test-Driven Development with Flask and Docker: Heroku: Getting State changed from starting to crashed

Tags: docker, heroku, testdriven.io

I am in the second part of the course Test-Driven Development with Python, Flask, and Docker
and I can't finish the first page of the second part because of this error, the application is still crushing.

```
2023-07-19T17:57:44.493049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-07-19T17:57:52.483423+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c gunicorn\ --bind\ 0.0.0.0:\38675\ manage:app`
2023-07-19T17:57:53.223594+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Exec format error
2023-07-19T17:57:53.342389+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126
2023-07-19T17:57:53.378816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-07-19T17:57:53.383032+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-07-19T17:58:00.212332+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c gunicorn\ --bind\ 0.0.0.0:\19658\ manage:app`
2023-07-19T17:58:02.174154+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Exec format error
2023-07-19T17:58:02.525768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126
2023-07-19T17:58:02.555917+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-07-19T18:00:06.130503+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-anchorage-69337-4897409e01ae.herokuapp.com request_id=007aa0c0-558e-4946-84e3-02c0615cb957 fwd="62.69.49.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-07-19T18:00:06.835057+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-anchorage-69337-4897409e01ae.herokuapp.com request_id=a8c552ed-6401-4445-9ec5-dfd66cb55433 fwd="62.69.49.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-07-19T18:00:11.578750+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/ping" host=fathomless-anchorage-69337-4897409e01ae.herokuapp.com request_id=b7a38e73-c618-4416-a376-ad51a36337b1 fwd="62.69.49.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-07-19T18:00:12.447910+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/ping" host=fathomless-anchorage-69337-4897409e01ae.herokuapp.com request_id=2bab3fae-a060-46fc-b795-f1cbb7d4a25e fwd="62.69.49.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-07-19T18:00:12.979501+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-anchorage-69337-4897409e01ae.herokuapp.com request_id=0db94061-bba8-4b15-80c8-35b77ddcff9f fwd="62.69.49.108" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

following the instructions of the course, but is not working.